# react-native axios interceptor where to ubicate

Tags: react-native, axios, interceptor

i have a interceptor with axios but i don't know where to ubicate it. i attach javascript

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import {getStoreData, checkStoreData} from './../utils/safestorage';

axios.interceptors.request.use(
  async config => {
    console.log('interceptor working');
    const checkUser = await checkStoreData('user');
    if (checkUser) {
      const data = await getStoreData('user');
      datajson = JSON.parse(data);
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${datajson.access_token}`;
      return config;
    }
  },
  error => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it importing the file in my app.js, an then my interceptors initialized.